# css priority, Most specific selector bug in firefox or calc on line-height not working?

Tags: html, css, firefox

CSS

```
.card {
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 0 5px;
}

.card .multi-material
{
    line-height:25px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="row">
        //Other columns
        <div class="col-xs-4 text-center text-ellipsis">
            <span class="pull-left material-quantity multi-material">9x  </span>
        </div>
        //Other columns
    </div>
</div>
```

For the span in the above scenario, firebox set line-height to 50 even if the most specific selector say 25. Chrome however is fine and use 25.

See what the firefox inspector give :
[image]

What should be done to fix the problem?

FYI : CSS is generated with LESS if this is of any help.

Comment: Tested your markup and works without a problem. You are inspecting parent element `.card` not the span that has the correct value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the question was misleading.

The actual line height wasn't a fixed number like I stated in the question. It was "calc(25px);" So basicly almost a fixed number. Chrome is able to interpret it but Firefox doesn't. As you can see, it's turned out that I don't need to use "calc" at all.

```
.card .multi-material
{
    line-height: calc(25px);
}
```

Removing the calc fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your selectors do not do what you're trying to achieve. In your current code you try to change the line-height of the child. But the line-height is previously applied to the parent (`.card)` not the child.

You would need something more like:

```
.card span {
    line-height: 50px; // need a unit measurement here, added px
    padding: 0 5px;
}

.card span.multi-material
{
    line-height:25px; // need a unit measurement here, added px
}
```

Comment: Ok, I understand your explication, but it's a bit more complicated cause doing that will break other stuff. However, I will try to get there tomorrow. Then I will let you know if it's worked or not. Thanks